# Policy with route group keeps returning 403

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, policies

I'm trying to use policy on a route group. I've included the bindings middleware and tried to list the ACTION and MODEL in the CAN middleware.

For some reason it keeps `returning 403`. Probably I didn't quite understood how the policies work.

I'm trying to enter the before method in the policy but It keeps `returning 403`. Also it would be lovely if someone explains how exactly should I list custom methods in the middleware.

I also did register my policy in the `AuthServiceProvider`

```php
  protected $policies = [
        Service::class => ServicePolicy::class,
    ];
```

```php
    public function before(CustomAuth0User $user, Service $service)
    {
        dd($service);
    }
```

```php
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'services', 'namespace' => 'Services', 'middleware' => ['bindings', 'can:getCancel, service']], function () {
        Route::get('/{service}/cancel', 'ServiceController@getCancel');
        Route::post('/{service}/cancel', 'ServiceController@postCancel');

        Route::get('/{id}/reassign', 'ServiceController@getReassign');
        Route::post('/{id}/reassign', 'ServiceController@postReassign');

        Route::get('/{id}/close', 'ServiceController@getClose');
        Route::post('/{id}/close', 'ServiceController@postClose');

        Route::get('/{id}/history', 'ServiceController@getHistory');
    });
```

`Controller`

```php
 public function getCancel(Service $service)
    {
        dd($service);
    }
```